# BigQuery resource used every 12h without configuring it

Tags: google-bigquery

I need some help to understand what happened to our cloud to have BigQuery resource running every 12h to our cloud without configuring it. Also, it seems very intense because we got charged, in average, one dollar every day for the past month.

After checking in Logs Explorer, I saw several logs regarding the BigQuery resource [image: (see attachment).]

I saw the email from one of our software guy. Since I removed him from our Firebase project, there is no more requests.

Though, that person did not do or configure anything regarding the BigQuery so we are a bit lost here and this is why we are asking some help to investigate and understand what is going on.

Hope you will be able to help. Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance

NB: I did not try to add the software guy's email yet. I wanted to see how it will go for the rest of the month.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely causes I've observed for this in the wild:

- A [scheduled query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) was setup by a user.
- A data studio dashboard was setup and configured to [periodically refresh](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039?hl=en) data in the background.
- Someone's setup a workflow the queries BigQuery, such as cloud composer or a cloud function, etc.

It's also possible its just something like a script running in a crontab on someone's machine.  The audit log should have relevant details like request origin for cases where it's just something running as part of a bespoke process.